# Things with [a] considerable likelihood of being

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Consider a sentence like this:

> ... only documents with [a] considerable likelihood of being ...

Should "a" be mentioned there considering that "documents" is plural?

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to say the article *(**a**)* is syntactically *necessary*, since Google Books claim 589 written instances of [*with considerable likelihood*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with+considerable+likelihood%22). But some people might be more fussy than me, and you should note that Google Books claims over 1000 instances of [*with **a** considerable likelihood,*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22with+a+considerable+likelihood%22) so it's probably best to side with that majority.

Comment: Personally I don't think the specific instance of ***a*** in your example would be affected by changing the referent to singular *...only **a document** with...* The "plurality" of the referent is irrelevant to this usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a problem with leaving the article in place.  The "a" is the determiner associated with the singular "likelihood". It is not associated with the plural "documents". The "a" can be dropped, but it should only be dropped for stylistic reasons, not because it does not agree in number to "documents".